# Is it possible to mock a method with using of Activator.CreateInstance()?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, moq

My method has a type parameter, so I am trying in my unit test to define a mock object and pass a type of it with a hope, that the instance of this type will mock the method as I have defined it. But if I call a method of my mock after I have created it with Activator.CreateInstance(), I become NotImplementedException.

Is it possible to mock a method with using of Activator.CreateInstance()?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDoFunc()
    {
        var vmod = new MyViewModel();
        var mock = new Mock<IAmAnInterface<MyViewModel>>();
        mock.Setup(x => x.DoInterfaceFunc(vmod)).Callback<MyViewModel>((viewModel) => { viewModel.Created = true; }).Returns(true);
        Assert.IsTrue(mock.Object.DoInterfaceFunc<MyViewModel>(vmod));//this works
        Assert.IsTrue(vmod.Created);//this works

        var mockObjFromActivator = Activator.CreateInstance(mock.Object.GetType()) as IAmAnInterface<MyViewModel>;
        Assert.IsTrue(mockObjFromActivator.DoInterfaceFunc<MyViewModel>(vmod));//this throw NotImplementedException
    }
}
public class MyViewModel { public bool Created { get; set; } }
public interface IAmAnInterface<TViewModel> { bool DoInterfaceFunc<TViewModel>(TViewModel vmod); }
```

EDIT:

I want to test such function:

```
void DoFunc(Type objType)
{
    var vmod = new MyViewModel();
    var objImplInterface = Activator.CreateInstance(objType) as IAmAnInterface<MyViewModel>;
    objImplInterface.DoInterfaceFunc(vmod);
    if (vmod.Created)
    {
        //more logic...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do very strange thing. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to create mock with `Activator.CreateInstance`. Are you trying to test a mock? Why would you do that?

Comment: No, I don't want to test a mock. May be bad naming. It's just an abstraction to reproduce an errror. There are more complex logic. I want test DoFunc(Type objType) { var vmod = new MyViewModel(); var objImplInterface=Activator.CreateInstance(objType) as IAmAnInterface<MyViewModel>; objImplInterface.DoInterfaceFunc(vmod); if(vmod.Created)......more logic }

Comment: Sounds like you need a factory to create instances of types you pass into `DoFunc` method which uses `Activator.CreateInstance`. Is it possible for you to change the implementation? If so I can show you how to do it.

Comment: Otherwise I don't think it is possible to achieve what you want with `Moq` as you don't have control over how mocks are created. I would suggest to create you custom fake implementation of `IAmAnInterface` for a test and pass its type in. You can code the behavior you want it to have for test.

Comment: It's a work around - to make a custom dummy implementation, but I have hoped to avoid it with Mock.

Comment: What is the edition of visual studio that you use?

Comment: VS 2015, does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

When I read your code I assume you want to test your `IAmAnInterface` interface. However you can only test a class which is an implementation of the interface because it contains code which describes what your method should do.

I would recommend your to write your test from scratch with the following in mind: use mocking when their are dependencies in your class or method which you are testing. Because it could be hard to manipulate the depended class for example to return an error, mocking those will make it easier to test various situations which can occur in your method.

I hope the example below would make it more clear.

Let say we have 2 classes with each their own interface:

```
public interface IFoo {
    string DoFuncX();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    IBar _bar;

    public Foo(IBar bar) {
        _bar = bar;
    }

    public string DoFuncX() {
        try {
            return _bar.DoFuncY();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "ERROR";
        }
    }
}

public interface IBar {
    string DoFuncY();
}

public class Bar : IBar {
    public string DoFuncY() {
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

and I want to test `DoFuncX` in class `Foo` and I expect that it enters in `catch` when `_bar.DoFunctY` throws an error:

```
Test__Foo_DoFuncX__IBar_Throws_Error() {

    // Arrange
    var mockedIBar = Mock<IBar>();
    mockedIBar.Setup(b => b.DoFuncY()).throw(new Exception("Mocked IBar Throws Errors"));

    // Act
    var foo = new Foo(mockedIBar);
    var result = foo.DoFuncX();

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(result, "ERROR");
}
```

*code can contains errors, but I think it makes clear what it should do.*

Comment: What to do, if you have   
public Foo(Type typeOfbar) { _bar = Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfbar) as IBar;}  
and many Bar1...BarN, which implement IBar?

Comment: This should also work when you pass an object but your won't be able to mock at least not with moq (It should be possible with Typemock). Besides of that I would not recommend to create an instance based on a type in a method with Activator. Instead of Type as parameter your can give an object like `IBar bar1 = new Bar1(); Foo(bar1); IBar2 bar2 = new Bar2(); Foo(bar2); IBar barN = new BarN(); Foo(barN);`. Because the interface of classes Bar1, Bar2... BarN is IBar. And if this need to be created dynamically you can use dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks, hakany, but I need to use this way - type as parameter, because of restrictions in another parts of a program. Andrii has offered a work around - to make a custom dummy implementation, which I have hoped to avoid with Mock.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the `CreateInstance` call. The obvious thing to do is to have `DoFunc` be passed a factory method instead or/as well as the `Type` (if it can't be passed the instance to use directly):

```
void DoFunc(Func<IAmAnInterface<MyViewModel>> factory)
{
    var vmod = new MyViewModel();
    var objImplInterface = factory();
    objImplInterface.DoInterfaceFunc(vmod);
    if (vmod.Created)
    {
        //more logic...
    }
}
```

Of course, you may be able to arrange for the factory to be supplied via other means, or for the instance to use to be injected by a dependency injection system.

This may mean changes, in turn, for how *whatever* contains `DoFunc` has to be created.

E.g. you may instead have a factory passed to the constructor that implements `Func<Type, IAmAnInterface<MyViewModel>` and you then later use that in `DoFunc`, and of course provide a mock during testing that hands back the mocked interface.

Comment: `DoFunc` is in ViewModel, the `objType` being set in XAML(View). I have not a possibility to set a function there.